# DateTime variable keep changes through execution

Tags: php, datetime, php-7

I'm experiencing a weird PHP operation. When I'm trying to work on `DateTime` and `DateInterval` and if I execute this code :

```
<?php
$dateTime = new \DateTime('2016-09-04');
$stepStart = $dateTime;

$dateTime->add(new \DateInterval('P2D'));

var_dump($stepStart);
die;
```

The `$stepStart` will have `2016-09-06` as a value, instead of the `2016-09-04` I was expecting.

More, if I add a `$stepStart->format('Y-m-d')` before adding 2 days the value is correct, I have `2016-09-04`.

Can someone explain that ?

Working on Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 7.0.10 (and tested on an OSX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$stepStart = $dateTime;` this is just create reference to $dateTime. If you want to have copy of this object, you must use CLONE

```
$stepStart = clone $dateTime;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Playing with objects/classes you must remember that they behave a little different than simple variables ;)